Why is there white spots on the stems of my tomatoes
Theres a kind of white i guess youd call it a fungus looking stuff growning on a couple of mt tomatoe plants

Please [edit] to add well lit, in focus, close-up pictures. While there are many fungal diseases of tomatoes, most are not white. On the other hand, certain aphids cloak themselves in a mass of white bubbles, which I suppose you might mistake for fungus if you didn't touch it. In any case, we can't see what you see if we don't have a picture showing it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's probably not a Fungi, it's likely to be an aphid which is a bug. Here's a picture.

Anyway cut to the chase, why? It is because they like tomatoes. :)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Community iConnor's answer is extremely straightforward.  There is nothing unclear about it at all.
